# Can I clear front page cache only?

Tags: caching

How to clear only the front page cache? I want to clear the front page cache when a new node is added.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Drupal 6 and 7 use the URL of the page as the cache ID (the `$cid`, see [`drupal_page_set_cache()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_page_set_cache/7)).  This should work.

```
$url = url('<front>',  array('absolute' => TRUE));
cache_clear_all($url, 'cache_page');
```

You will need to adjust the logic a bit if you can access the site through multiple URLs.

Answer (score 1):

Give a try to [Flush page cache](https://drupal.org/project/flush_page_cache) module:

> Flushing Drupal's cache on a large site can feel like you're waiting to takeoff on the tarmac at JFK. The delay comes from the fact that when you clear Drupal's cache, it clears everything. Most of time you just want to flush the cache for specific object on a page.The 'Flush page cache' module solves this problem by flushing only the cached objects for a single page. Additionally, you can define custom objects and cache tables to be cleared on specific pages

Use cases:

- You have nodes nested in views nested in a panel page. You've edited a node that's displayed on this page, but you want the change to be seen immediately.
- You have a large team of non-technical content editors who frequently run into the scenario above and you want to give them an easy, one-button solution to their content being updated in the lists they manage.
- You've just cleared the entire website's cache through the normal means and for whatever reason, a few pages are rendered and cached in a broken state.

Answer (score 0):

Using drush is the fastest way to clear cache.

// clear all

`drush cc all`

// individual caches to clear

`drush cc theme-registry`

`drush cc menu`

`drush cc css-js`

`drush cc block`

`drush cc registry`

`drush cc views`

I found a blog post which shows how to clear a single page with drush. *disclaimer* I have not tried this method personally. [Clear a single page cache drush](http://www.gerritbrands.com/blog/clear-single-page-cache-drush)

```
drush sqlq "DELETE FROM cache_page WHERE cid = 'http://example.com/'"
```

or with using a drush alias

```
drush @your_alias sqlq "DELETE FROM cache_page WHERE cid = 'http://example.com/'"
```

Comment: -1. The question is to clear only the front page cache.

Comment: Clear a single page cache example clearly shows clearing the front page only and can be used for any particular page. Yes, I provided additional options to clear caches but is that against the rules at drupal stack exchange?

Comment: That should be added to comment. It is least relevant to consider it as an answer, IMO.

Comment: The question says "I want to clear the front page cache when a node is added."  Clearing cache with drush doesn't help that use case.  And using sql to clear the cache doesn't work if memcache is being used.

Comment: What happens when caching is handled by Varnish/Boost/nginx/etc ?